# Central Limit Theorem - show that random variable X is normal with expected value 0.

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose X, Y, Z are i.i.d. random variables. Show that if $\mathbb{E}|X^2| < \infty$ and
$$
X \stackrel{D}{=}\frac{Y + Z}{\sqrt2}
$$

then X has a normal distribution with expected value 0.

I suppose I have to use Lindenberg's CLT here? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Say $X_1,X_2,\dots$ are iid, satisfying that sum condition. Let $$S_n=\frac1{\sqrt n}(X_1+\dots+X_n).$$

Say $X_j\sim\mu$. Then $\frac1
{\sqrt2
}(X_1+X_2)\sim\mu$ and also $\frac1
{\sqrt2
}(X_3+X_4)\sim\mu$; since $$S_4=\frac{\frac{X_1+X_2}{\sqrt2}+\frac{X_3+X_4}{\sqrt2}}{\sqrt 2}$$it follows that $$S_4\sim\mu.$$By induction in fact $$S_{2^k}\sim\mu;$$now apply CLT...